# SQL Server always encrypted and JpaRepository in SpringBoot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, encryption, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to integrate SQL SERVER column level encryption with a Spring Boot application, without success. In my application I defined an entity called Transaction

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTIONS")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "INSERT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDate insertTimestamp;
...
}
```

And a JPA repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, String> { ... }
```

In my SQL SERVER 2019 I have defined this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS](
    [transaction_id] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [amount] [numeric](16,2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
    [insert_timestamp] [date] NULL,
    [description] [varchar](1024) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [TRANSACTIONS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [transaction_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then I defined an endpoint:

```
@PostMapping
public Transaction saveTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction request){
...
}
```

From Postman, I'm calling the endpoint with this body:

```
{
    "amount":120.0,
    "description":"TV"
}
```

But I get this error:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: decimal(18,1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'BANK') is incompatible with numeric(16,2) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'BANK')`

Since the error states an operand type clash, I modified the data type in the DB table, so from `[amount] [numeric](16,2)` to `[amount] [decimal](18,1)`.
Now, ironically let me say, the error is:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: numeric(4,1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'BANK') is incompatible with decimal(18,1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'BANK')`

I also tried to use Double for the amount on Java entity and float for amount on DB table. This works, but I would like to use numeric(16,2) data type on DB.

Please notice I have this error only for decimal/numeric data types, everything works fine if I use varchar or integers.

Any ideas?